# Angular using require.js is not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am having issues with FireFox and Opera not rendering my application. While Chrome and IE work just fine.

I think I have narrowed down the problem, and it happens after this gets executed:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="lib/require/require-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

This is the content of js/main:

```
 require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min',
    bootstrap: '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
    underscore: '../lib/underscore/underscore',
    angular: '../lib/angular/angular',
    angularResource: '../lib/angular/angular-resource',
    text: '../lib/require/text'
  },
  shim: {
    'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
    'angular-resource' : {deps:['angular']},
    'bootstrap': {deps:['jquery']},
    'underscore': {exports: '_'}
  },
  baseUrl: 'js/',

  priority: [
    "angular"
  ],
  urlArgs: 'v=1.1'
});

require( [
  'angular',
  'app',
  'services/services',
  'controllers/controllers',
  'controllers/navbar',
  'filters/filters',
  'directives/directives',
  'routes'
], function(angular, app) {   

  angular.element(document).ready(function () { //BREAKPOINT SET HERE
      console.log("Getting ready to bootstrap: ");
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  });
});
```

And as I mentioned before it works in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Attached is a screenshot, with the breakpoint set in main.js (comments shows the location of breakpoint). Screenshot shows local variables both in FF and Chrome... Those in Chrome have been loaded properly, while the ones in FF are not.

I am thinking this is small issue, but I cant find it. Any help is appreciated !!!

[image: requirejs]

Comment: Re: *"Those in Chrome have been loaded properly, while the ones in FF are not"*: say how these two sets of variables differ, I doubt many potential helpers would spend time trying to spot the difference comparing the lists on the screenshots (I gave up after 30 seconds)

Comment: angular + require.js that way does not give you any benefits (only complex code with 2 levels of dependency injection). check out [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw) and boil your own solution. require.js is merely used as a script loader.

Comment: kryger, I am sorry if I have made that impression. I did not want anyone to compare those two images, it is clear after 10 second of looking that 90% is stuff is missing. This image is more like a "evidence" that it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, it would work in chrome but not firefox.

i managed to get it to work using the following. This is using ng-app in the html and basically puts on hold the bootstrap process untill requirejs is finished with its magic.

```
window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

/* require config here */

requirejs(['jquery','underscore','angularjs'], function ($, _ ) {
/* create angular app here */
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.resumeBootstrap();
 });
}
```

I am using angularjs 1.2.0rc3 and tested in FF 24, Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m, IE 10

Comment: thank you for comment. How would I implement your solution? Place it all in index.html file... or?

Comment: You just need to apply that to your js/main file.. Put each line in its equivalent position in your file.

Comment: I am having problems incorporating your solution to my main.js file. Can you help me more?